# GPU Instancing with multiple Materials

Tags: unity-game-engine, gpu, game-development, gpu-instancing, materials

I'm making use of GPU Instancing in my 3D game in Unity.
Currently I'm using single material for each mesh.
But is there a way to do that with multiple material?
I have mesh's with just material colors without any textures, so texture atlas not helping in this case, is there way to Instance single mesh with multiple material.

Trying to find the solution of this from long time, requesting the solution.

Comment: Why can't you check the "GPU instancing" option in inspector settings of each material individually?

Comment: Already did that want, to Instanced mesh with GPU.